# Knockout with coffeescript

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

I am going to use Knockout with Coffeescript. Following is simple sample code.

```
**** coffeescript ****
    class NewsItem
        constructor : (content) ->
            @content = ko.observable(content)

    class ViewModel
        constructor : ->        
            @items = ko.observableArray()
            @item = ko.observable()

            @items.push new NewsItem('a')
            @items.push new NewsItem('b')
            @items.push new NewsItem('c')

            @addItem = ->
                @items.push new NewsItem @item()

    $ ->
        ko.applyBindings new ViewModel
        return  

**** html ****
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        <li data-bind="text: $data.content"></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: item" />
        <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
    </div>
```

Above code is working well. What I am wondering is that I should declare addItem event using ***this*** keyword as above or ***prototype*** member as follow

```
class NewsItem
    constructor : (content) ->
        @content = ko.observable(content)

class ViewModel
    constructor : ->        
        @items = ko.observableArray()
        @item = ko.observable()

        @items.push new NewsItem('a')
        @items.push new NewsItem('b')
        @items.push new NewsItem('c')

    addItem : ->
        console.log @item()
        @items.push new NewsItem @item()

$ ->
    ko.applyBindings new ViewModel
    return
```

I understand observable properties (content, items, item) should be instance member using ***this*** keyword to avoid sharing value among instance objects. That's ok, but what about event functions such as **addItem** method in my case

Comment: if it is anything to go on, I have always declared my methods for use by data-binds like you have in the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine in the second case, just try it ;).

```
class Randomized
  constructor: -> @items = [Math.random()]
  first: -> @items[0]

console.log new Randomized().first()
console.log new Randomized().first()
console.log new Randomized().first()
```

Comment: is that an okay answer or were there another question I missed?